# JavaScript function "help text" in console

Tags: javascript, function

I'm curious to know how one could easily annotate a JavaScript function with textual information (description of what function does, which parameters are used, returned etc..), so that one can access it from the console.

In Matlab for example this is done by commenting text right beneath the function's header, and accessing it by typing `help myFunction` in the console.

Example from [Mathworks](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-help-for-your-program.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop):

```
myFunction c = addme(a,b)
% ADDME  Add two values together.
%   C = ADDME(A) adds A to itself.
%   C = ADDME(A,B) adds A and B together.
%
%   See also SUM, PLUS.

switch nargin
    case 2
        c = a + b;
    case 1
        c = a + a;
    otherwise
        c = 0;
end
```

What is the (or an) equivalent approach in JavaScript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Code_comments

Comment: @Bergi that's not addressing what I ask, because simple comments as described in your link cannot be viewed in the console. thanks anyway

Comment: Well the console doesn't display anything by default, but you can display the source of a function (including comments) by using `myFunction.toString()`

Comment: @Bergi oh right, that would be another option indeed. But less handy and quite impractical if the entire function is fairly long. duskwuff's solution seems more convenient to me, though yours has the advantage of requiring no extra text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript isn't really geared for interactive use, so there's no standard pattern for this in the language.

Functions are objects, though. So you could assign a value to `myFunction.help`:

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
    …
}
myFunction.help = "Here is some help text";
```

This value wouldn't be specifically exposed anywhere in the console, but would be available by reading `myFunction.help`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that this isn't possible in the same way as in Matlab, and many thanks as well for providing an alternative: as some functions I use contain many (optional) parameters, it can be helpful to view them on the fly from the console, so your object oriented solution will work great.

Comment: just realized that the definition of the `.help` attribute can also be included inside the function, e.g. right below the header, which makes it more organized and readable  when reading from the script itself.

Comment: Including the assignment to `.help` within the function would make it impossible to view the help message without first running the function at least once.

Answer (score 1):

You can add documentation (params, return, behavior etc) to a JS function using [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html). But it is not available in an interactive way like you need. It includes a document generator which can generate user-friendly (static) HTML pages out of the documentation, which you can browse.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this option, but I was more looking for something interactive, as duskwuff suggested.